# What are the new guns in the Torgue DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm vaguely familiar with the Torgue legendaries from the main game (Flakker, Nukem and such) but casually glancing at the legendaries in the Torgue vending machines I've never quite noticed which are the new ones. Unlike the Pirate's Booty DLC the new weapons seem to blend in with the old one (new guns were either pink or "cursed" blue guns with little in between)

So far I've found an Expansive Kitten and Moxxie's Slow Hand (a quest reward and a rare drop IIRC) but I'm not sure what the other new guns are. A google search doesn't really yield helpful results.

So what are the new guns in Mister Torgue's Campaign of Carnage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wiki says there are 5 new weapons introduced in the DLC. There are four new Uniques (blue): The Cobra, The Pocket Rocket, The Boom Puppy, and The Kitten, as well as a new E-Tech shotgun called the Slow Hand. There are no new Legendaries sadly. All of the orange Tourgue weapons in the vending machines can be found as possible drops in the general campaign.

Answer (score 0):

The only two I've found as being exclusive to Campaign of Carnage are [Pocket Rocket](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Pocket_Rocket) and [Cobra](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Cobra_%28Borderlands_2%29), but I have to believe there are more than that.

Comment: These are probably the only two new **uniques**. There are probably quite some legendaries, but a skim over wiki didn't get me a list of those.

Comment: @OrcJMR there are more uniques; the Kitten and Slow Hand are uniuqes too (blue and magenta/e-tech). I'd like to know all of them though the most interesting for me are legendaries since they're only(?) in the Torgue vendor

Answer (score 0):

Among the two you have listed, I also have received the "Tiny Tina's Boom Puppy" assault rifle. The Kitten, as far as I know, can have many different versions (I have a Slag Kitten)